# Как правильно настроить htaccess под поисковые системы?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, robots.txt

У меня есть сайт, на котором появляются товары, под каждый товар создаётся страница. Через определенное время, этот товар может быть удалён, а поисковый робот эту страницу уже просканирует и при повторном посещении в Вебмастере и в Гугл Консоли будут ошибки о несуществующих страницах.

Как правильно настроить этот момент для SEO, чтобы не было проблем с поисковой оптимизацией ?
Переадресация на 404 страницу стоит, но это не решает как я понимаю проблему. Как сделать правильно?